# Writing a twitter bot with node.js - what am I doing wrong?

Tags: javascript, node.js, twitter, bots

I've written this twitterbot using different tutorials for the twit and twitter libraries. I'd like it to execute different functions at different intervals (haven't written this part yet). The different functions work when I comment out the rest, but if I try to run everything together I get different errors. Also, the function using the Rest-API (replyToTweets, line 106) doesn't do anything at all. Hope someone can help. Thanks!

```
var fs = require('fs'),
    path = require('path'),
    Twit = require('twit'),
    config = require(path.join(__dirname, 'config.js')),
    TwitterPackage = require('twitter');

var T = new Twit(config);
var Twitter = new TwitterPackage(config);


// A - For posting a Tweet.
function postTweet() {
    console.log('A beginnt...')
        T.post('statuses/update', {status: 'Bleh..' }, function(err, data, response) {
            console.log(data)
});
};


// B - For posting images
//pick random image from the array
function postRandomImage() {
    console.log('B beginnt...')
    function pick_random_image() {
        var images = [
        'wurst.jpg',
        'wurst.jpg'
    ];
        return images[Math.floor(Math.random() * images.length) ];
    }

    //upload image:
    function upload_random_image() {
        console.log('Bild oeffnen...');
        var image_path = path.join(__dirname, '/bilder/' + pick_random_image()),
            b64content = fs.readFileSync(image_path, { encoding: 'base64' });

        console.log('Bild hochladen...');

        T.post('media/upload', { media_data: b64content }, function (err, data, response) {
            if(err) {
                console.log('ERROR');
                console.log(err);
            }
            else {
                console.log('Bild erfolgreich hochgeladen');

                T.post('statuses/update', {
                    media_ids: new Array(data.media_id_string)
                },
                       function(err, data, response) {
                            if (err) {
                                console.log('ERROR');
                                console.log(err);
                            }
                            else{
                                console.log('Bild gepostet');
                            }
                        }
                );
            }
        });
    }
}


// C - reply to mentions/replies
function replyToMentions(){
    var stream = T.stream('user');

    stream.on('tweet', tweetEvent);

    function tweetEvent(eventMsg) {

        console.log('C beginnt...');

        var replyto = eventMsg.in_reply_to_screen_name;
        var text = eventMsg.text;
        var from = eventMsg.user.screen_name;

        console.log(replyto + ' ' + from);

        if (replyto === 'xxxx') {
            var newtweet = '.@' + from + ' http://gph.is/1l7SWLL?tc=1';
            tweetIt(newtweet);
        }
    }

    function tweetIt(txt) {
        var tweet = { status: txt }

        T.post('statuses/update', tweet, tweeted);

        function tweeted(err, data, response) {
            if (err) {
                console.log('ERROR');
                console.log(err);
            } else {
                console.log('It worked.');
            }
        }
    }
};


//D - use Rest-API to react to tweets that use certain keywords
function replyToTweets() {
    console.log('D beginnt ...');
    Twitter.stream('statuses/filter', {track: 'Wawawawa'}, function(stream) {
        stream.on('data', function(tweet) {
            console.log(tweet.text);

            var statusObj = { status: ".@" + tweet.user.screen_name + "http://gph.is/2mKyBTs?tc=1" }

            Twitter.post('statuses/update', statusObj, function(error, tweetReply, response) {
                if(error){
                    console.log(error);
                }

                console.log(tweetReply.text);
            })
        });

        stream.on('error', function(error) {
            console.log(error);
        });
    });
};


//E - answer a specific question with a specific answer
function replyToQuestion(){
    console.log('E beginnt...');
    var stream = T.stream('user');

    stream.on('tweet', tweetEvent);

    function tweetEvent(eventMsg) {

        console.log('E beginnt...');

        var replyto = eventMsg.in_reply_to_screen_name;
        var text = eventMsg.text;
        var from = eventMsg.user.screen_name;

        console.log(replyto + ' ' + from);

        if (text === '@xxxx Ist Donald Trump noch im Amt?') {
            var newtweet = '@' + from + ' leider ja.';
            tweetIt(newtweet);
        }
    }

    function tweetIt(txt) {
        var tweet = { status: txt }

        T.post('statuses/update', tweet, tweeted);

        function tweeted(err, data, response) {
            if (err) {
                console.log('ERROR');
                console.log(err);
            } else {
                console.log('It worked.');
            }
        }
    }
};




function begin() {
    replyToMentions();
    replyToTweets();
    postTweet();
    postRandomImage();
    replyToQuestion();
};

/*setInterval(
    begin(),
    60000
)
*/
```

Comment: You could have at least translated the comments. Not a lot of people here understand German. And why are some functions named in German, and some in English, and then both languages have function names mixed in camel case and snake case?

Comment: @simbabque Oh I'm sorry, I thought I did! Must have posted the wrong one, my bad. Thank you for the comment about the functions, that's not pretty, probably did that because I copied from different tutorials

Comment: `The different functions work when I comment out the rest, but if I try to run everything together I get different errors.` What works and what doesn't? What errors do you get? Please be more specific.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's an async trouble in 98% I think. You can use promises and wait to they are solved before the next function. Also you can stop the next function if the last promise has an error. **wait to a function finishes, then continue with the next function **. That's the cause that your functions work individually but not in serial.

*This is a dirty code, but works, and i put this you to make easy understand of using Callbacks and Promises, two ways to solve your problem.*

**Update without promises**

Let's asume this functions:

```
function A(done){
    console.log('hello from A');
    done();
}

function B(done){
    console.log('hello from B');
    done();
}

function begin(){
    A(function(){
        console.log('A is finished, im going to call B');
        B(function(){
            console.log('B is finished');
        });
    });
}
```

**Update with promises**

```
function A(done){
    console.log('hello from A');
    done();
}

function B(done){
    console.log('hello from B');
    done();
}

function begin(){
    var promises = [];
    promises.push(A);
    Promise.all(promises).then(function(){
        console.log('A is finished, im going to call B');
        promises = [];
        promises.push(B);
        Promise.all(promises).then(function(){
            console.log('B is finished');   
        });
    })
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much! I'm new to coding, could you give me an example of how to do this? Like what do I have to add to the code to tell my app to continue with the next function?

Comment: Thanks for explaining this so patiently. It solved my problem, and what is more, I understand it :)

Comment: Ok check as valid answer please :)